# Проблема с favicon

Tags: wordpress, favicon

Всем привет! Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему при добавлении фавикона грузит изначальной базовый фавикон вордпрес, а потом уже мой. Мой фавикон находится в корневой папке сайта

Вот пример:
https://nellys-charm.com/product/plate-pl4-034-08-frez/

Comment: Кто, где "грузит"?

Comment: ОМГ... https://i.imgur.com/fKT6416.jpeg

Comment: Выкиньте этот плагин All-In-One Favicon, пользуйтесь стандартными средствами WordPress. Плагин не обновлялся более года, не проверялся с 3 мажорными версиями WP, вы зачем этот хлам вообще на сайт ставите?

Comment: Что "ОМГ", фавикон добавлен не через плагин

Answer (score 1):

В целом, вы делаете всё неправильно. Вам не нужен плагин  All-In-One Favicon. Стандартные средства WP позволяют добавить свой файл favicon, и это будет нормально работать.

Если уж очень хочется оставить всё как есть, то уберите стандартный хук WP, который выводит favicon по умолчанию. Добавьте этот код в `functions.php` вашей темы:

```
/**
 * Remove default favicon action.
 */
function remove_wp_favicon() {
    remove_action( 'do_favicon', 'do_favicon' );
}

add_action( 'do_favicon', 'remove_wp_favicon', 0 );
```